# Fanless, LTE and thunderbolt convertible / 2-in-1 / tablet laptop suggestion?

Tags: laptop, tablet, thunderbolt, fanless

I would highly appreciate your suggestions regarding the device I have been searching for last couple of months.
Please accept my apologies for the long question, I found no other way to ask my doubts than asking what I search for and explain a bit what I have already found.

I am looking for a 2-in-1 to replace the device I am taking with me currently.
-Currently I have an android tablet 10 inches which fits perfectly into my purse, 
I mainly use it for web surfing and checking my mails, and for fun playing some casual non demanding games both out of home and when back home sitting on the sofa next to my wife,  I would like some text exiting and even spreadsheet, and reply to mails with keyboard.
What happens is that due to the keyboard and also programs missing, I find myself waiting for some email answers if they have to be long, and for text editing, to when back home ( I did buy a bluetooth keyboard, logitech and by the way expensive, after a few falls some keys fell from it and also never worked really fine).

As a replacement I would like an improvement, something, touch display:
- with keyboard, but that I could use as tablet also.
-that was capable of word editing and spreadsheets, but offered me some fun possibilities also

As far as I know I have several options:
A) Chrome OS : I don't like having to use drive,  I prefer having programs locally and having a large number of Windows or Android apps/programs available.
B)Apple: I respect but I prefer Windows or even Android as I am more used to it and am an android smartphone and windows user.
C) Windows next releases with Snapdragon 835, which I discard due to limited windows programs compatibility of these arm-based devices.
D) Android with a keyboard :    That is not my prefered option but still there and will go for it if I find nothing. I would probably wait a few weeks and buy the next Galaxy tab S4 which is like 10.5", Android 8.0 oreo, and get it with keyboard and LTE, as Huawei Mediapad M5 just released lacks of audio jack. (Lenovo yoga book looks fancy but the halo keyboard seems unpractical and is android 7.0).
E) A windows 10 convertible /2 in 1 which is more expensive but my prefered option.
And to find something is where I need your help:

I am trying to find options, if possible not crazy expensive but seeing things I will have to spend more than 1200€ by quite for sure. I was hoping about 1300€ but I think will be more.

The specifications I am looking for are:

-‎fanless so I can use it anywhere silently, as I don't use demanding programs
-‎A device which would last long time, some years ahead taking into account future connectivity, so would like at least one  Thunderbolt 3. Also that way would be smaller and can lack of other connections that you could get through a multiple port.
-‎with LTE capabilities : don't like using the hotspot and after all wtf if I spend that money at least I expect the same connectivity I will get with an android tablet with LTE, which is much cheaper, and despite smaller screen and no thunderbolt offers now options for word processing.
-‎Here a question: will with android 8.0 oreo be possible  to use a mouse and multi - window so you get a pc-like if you add a keyboard with mouse?.
- small size so it fits in my purse or similar (here screen size will be one size or another depending on the bezel). Max size of the device for me is ‎11.5 inch (29cm) wide, maybe even 11.8" (30cm), which should be more than 12" screen but with that device size probably will not surpass 12.6".
- ‎screen 3:2
- ‎8 ram 256 or higher ssd if possible upgradeable
- Ideally should have a light tablet-like charger to carry with me
- spanish keyboard, although this will be offered by most producers if I find the device in Spain (for example Eve-V lacks of both spanish keyboard and LTE, like most chinese brands like Teclast, Chuwi, Cube...)

The final contenders are:
Dell latitude 7285 2 in 1 is definitely an option but too expensive 2000€
HP elite X2 1012 G1 with lte is definitely an option also around 1500€

Very interesting HP envy with intel processor which will be released soon might be an option (and I prefer its kind of screen stand to the elite X2 and dell 7285 ones) but initially will lack of thunderbolt and LTE!!

Another interesting option is getting a 11.5" affordable Asus vivobook flip 12 fanless with hdd and replacing the 500gb hdd by an ssd which can be done, turning it into totally fanless, but lacks of thunderbolt and lte of course (but cheap and at least has usb type c)

Some discarded ones: (If I'm not wrong):

Lenovo thinkpad x1 tablet depending on the generation lacks some of these
Toshiba portege z20t lacks thunderbolt and very thick
Microsoft surface lacks of thunderbolt...and even type c
Asus models I found lack of LTE...
Same with passively  cooled acer
Huawei matebook e neither lte nor thunderbolt

Any further ideas? Am I missing something? Hopefully some of you know/own  one model besides the HP elite x2 1012 G1 and the Dell 7285 with these characteristics, already existing or about to be released.

I am only an end user with some basic acknoweledge so I ask for your comprehension if something I wrote is wrong :)

I would wait for a release later this year gladly...or take an older model with less powerful fanless processor if still can be found

Many thanks in advance